# Appstore Submit Primary language error?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm planing to submit the app in Appstore, and the primary which is selected is English (US). I want my app published in US store but while click submit for review it show error with primary language.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you upload binary to itunes ?

Comment: Yes uploaded, when i Submit for review i got this

Comment: But in this screenshot it shows prepare for submission

Comment: Yes if i click on that it will change to submitted for review

Comment: it will not change to submit for review
have your read ever https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html 
this link or directly upload your app ?

Comment: Yes what i followed is same way , i uploaded binary , screens shot etc.  After this on submit for review...this error came.. i think i have registered account to wrong store.. because it shows some korean trade enable settings below..screen shot attched in question please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120850/discussion-between-ashish-thakkar-and-nikey).

Comment: Make sure you have at least one screenshot for every device size. If you already do, ensure that your app name is unique (two apps in the same localization cannot have the same name)

Comment: thanks @Jojodmo it is resolved after updating the screens for 3.5 inch screen , but actually I'm not supporting the App to 3.5 inch screen...In that case what should i do

Comment: @nikey I think you still have to include it as long as your app supports <= iOS 8... If it only supports iOS 9, then I'm not quite sure... I assume you would still need screenshots, although they wouldn't be seen by anyone other than the app store reviewers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missed Adding Screen shots for 3.5 inch screen, After adding issue got resolved.

Thanks to every one for the help

Comment: You should accept this answer so others can find it easier.

Comment: Well, the error message is not giving a lot of information. I found out that you need to have at least 1 screenshot for ALLLLL the options. not just the 3.5 inch. Even if you don't support Apple watch, you still should upload the screenshot!